# Is my argument for unique solution of $\sin x = x$ valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The exercise I made for myself was to prove that $x = 0$ is the only solution to $\sin x = x$. The first step is to prove that there are no positive solutions. For any solution $a$, since $\sin a = a$ and $-1\le\sin a\le1$ we know that $-1\le a\le1$. This means there are no solutions for $a\gt 1$. Now if we assume that $a \in (0,\pi/2)$ then by the unit circle

$$\cos x \lt 1 \quad\text{on $(0,a)$}$$ $$\int_0^a \cos x \lt \int_0^a 1$$ $$\sin a - \sin0 \lt a - 0$$ $$\sin a \lt a$$
Therefore $\sin a \not= a$ for $a \in (0,\pi/2)$ and $a \in (1,\infty)$ so that $(0,\infty)$ contains no solutions. Any potential nonzero solution must be negative, but $$\sin a = a$$ $$-\sin a = -a$$ $$\sin{-a} = -a$$ If any solution $a \lt 0$ exists, then a positive solution also exists, which is impossible. There are no solutions for $a \lt 0$ or $a \gt 0$ so $a = 0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're willing to do calculus, let $f(x) = x-\sin x.$  Then $f'(x)= 1 - \cos x$ which is always greater than or equal to zero.  Therefore $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing and can equal zero only once.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way.

Assume that you have a unit circle, centered at $~(0,0),~$ and assume that you have an arc of the circle, that starts at $~(1,0),~$ and travels along the circumference of the circle, towards $~(0,1).$

Assume that $~\theta~$ is the length of this arc, which implies that $0 < \theta < \pi/2.$

Then, assume that the endpoint of this arc has coordinates
$~(x,y)~$ so that $~x = \cos(\theta), ~y = \sin(\theta).$

Clearly, the value $~y,~$ which represents the *height* of this arc length, is less than the length of the arc itself.

Since $~\theta~$ represents the length of this arc, this establishes that $~\theta > \sin(\theta).$

---

**Edit**
Imagine the right triangle formed by the vertices $(1,0), (x,y), (x,0).$

Clearly, the arc length $~\theta~$ is greater than the hypotenuse of this right triangle, since the shortest distance between two points is a straight line.  Further, the value $~y,~$ which represents the length of one of the legs of the right triangle must be less than the length of the hypotenuse.

**Edit**
See also the comment of Thomas Andrews, immediately following this answer, which gives an even more elegant geometric analysis.

Comment: It's easier to use the more intuitive "shortest distance between two points is a line," so $2\sin x$ is the distance from $(\cos x,\sin x)$ and $(\cos x,-\sin x),$ which is also $2x$ away along the circle. It is true about the perpendicular, but that isn't an intuitively true statement, unlike the traditional "shortest distance is a line" statement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews +1 : That's a nice comment.  I added a trailer reference in my answer.